# How to change Bootstrap grid system with media-query

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My table is using Bootstrap grid system.

What I want is to get rid of a column when the screen width is below 700px.

Here is what I have :

HTML

```
<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-xs-1">#</th>
                            <th id="when" class="col-xs-2">When</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-5">Track ID</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2 tracklink"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                            <th id="buy" class="col-xs-1 tracklink"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1" id="audio"></th> <!-- column to show sound icon when playing-->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id='trackinfo'>
                        <tr>
                            <td id='order' class="col-xs-1">1</td>
                            <td id='timecue' class="col-xs-2">00:00</td>
                            <td id='song' class="col-xs-5 song-tracklist">Korama - Pretty Baby</td>
                            <td id='link' class="col-xs-2 tracklink"><a href='http://www.google.fr' target="_blank" class="tracklink">Link</a></td>
                            <td id='link' class="col-xs-1 tracklink"><a href='http://www.google.fr' target="_blank" class="tracklink">Link</a></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-1" id="audio"><i class="fa fa-volume-up tracklink-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #audio{ 
display: none; }
}
```

You can see that the last column with id="audio" disappears with screen below 700px width.

Therefore, the class="col-xs-1" goes away with it and the whole table gets messed up.

To re-balance it, I want to turn the class="col-xs-5" into class="col-xs-6" when the screen is below 700px width.

I tried adding a class="col-xs-6" next to class="col-xs-5" and added a CSS to hide one/show the other above/below 700px :

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
th td .col-xs-6 { 
display: block; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
th td .col-xs-5 { 
display: none; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
th td .col-xs-6 { 
display: none; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
th td .col-xs-5 { 
display: block; }
}
```

However, it does not seem to work.

Please help me turning class="col-xs-5" into class="col-xs-6" when the screen gets below 700px width.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to use a breakpoint at 700px, instead of relying on the bootstrap breakpoints, the closest being `xs` with 768px? If you chose to use that breakpoint instead, the solution to the problem would be quite easy. You could also move the `xs` breakpoint ENTIRELY to 700px, you could [customize your bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/) and [change the breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints)

Comment: the problem is "#audio" should be change to ".audio" and <td id="audio"> to <td class="audio">. You know why? Because browser doesn't accept 2 id and this has messed up your table

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
th td .col-xs-5 { 
width:50%;
 }
}
```